# Valid Array generation for ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I want to create a `ListDensityPlot` of `T` vs `k`, and to do so I am not able to achieve an appropriate `Array` output from my code. The code is

```
eq[\[Alpha]_, k_, T_] := \[Alpha]*Sin[k + \[Alpha]] == T*Cos[k];
sol[T_?NumericQ,k_ /; 0 <= k <= Pi/2] := \[Alpha] /.NSolve[{eq[\[Alpha],k,T], 0 <= \[Alpha] <= Pi/2}, \[Alpha], 
 Reals] /. \[Alpha] -> {};

Table[With[{v = -2.5, \[Alpha] = 1}, 
Block[{w = -2 Cos[k], \[Delta] = v - w + (T*Sin[k]^2)/(Sin[2*k + sol[T,k]]^2 + T*Sin[k]^2), \[Rho] = 
 v - w + (\[Alpha]*T*Abs[\[Delta] - E^(I*k)]^2)/(
  1 + T*Abs[\[Delta] - E^(I*k)]^2) }, Abs[(E^(I k) - 
   E^(-I k))/(1 + (\[Rho] - E^(I k)) (E^(
      I k) - \[Delta]))]^2]], {T, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1}, {k, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1}]
```

I am however able to make a `ListLinePlot` by using `Flatten@Table[...]`. The output I get is something like `{{{a},{b},{c}},{{d},{e},{f}},{{g},{h},{i}}}` which should instead be like `{{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}`? for making a `ListDensityPlot` for `T` vs `k`.

Answer (score 1):

Table works by returning lists of lists of outputs. You can use this inelegant approach to fix the format:

```
Do[t[[i]] = t[[i]] // Flatten, {i, 3}]
```

I think if you understand head (3rd argument of Flatten) you might be able to skip the loop.

You should try giving more minimal examples, eg. by using Table[foo[args], ...]. The numbers obfuscate your code.